# How to configure visual studio's solution to open/compile wix projects without wix 3.6 installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

How to configure visual studio's solution to open/compile wix projects without wix 3.6 installing on the machine?

In other words the situation that I want to get is: developer after "Get Latest", together with sources, get all wix tools when solution is ready yo use them (build msi).

I have seen the article about that a half of year ago but now I can't find it without your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you mention is likely the one describing how to build WiX projects on a build server where WiX Toolset is not installed the usual way (via MSI package). It is called [Integrating WiX Projects into the daily builds](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/daily_builds.htm) and is also available in WiX.chm under Working with MSBuild folder.

You'll be able to build WiX projects on a build server and locally on a developer machine, but not from the Visual Studio - for the reason explained by Bob in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Visual Studio requires a separate VSPackage to understand project types (like .wixproj) that aren't "in the box." For WiX, that requires installing Votive, the WiX project system for VS.